# how to integrate piwik-wrap in your nodejs javascript website hosted locally

Tags: javascript, npm, nodes, matomo

Hi I am trying to integrate piwik-wrap (- A Promise-based wrapper for the Piwik JavaScript Tracking Client). I have followed the steps from https://www.npmjs.com/package/piwik-wrap

let me describe my steps:

First let me tell you its a Single page application.

This is how my package.json looks:

[image: package.json]

Then I added piwik-wrap explicitly in the pages where the routes are present

Also I piwik hostly in my server like this. and I have added the website name "eoc-local" as https://localhost:3000/search

[image: piwik hosted]

Its showing Piwik-wrap no declared . I had added it explicitly. Please advice !
Also its showing setcustomurl is not a fucntion

[image: its showing setcustomurl is not a fucntion]

Comment: Can you add your code to your post ? "I had added it explicitly" is not really helpful for us.

Comment: @Seblor: HI , pls have a look

Comment: So the error you have at line 47 is "Piwik-wrap no declared" ? and How did you declare "Piwik-wrap" ?

Comment: @ using imports I have imported piwik wrap

Comment: We need the exact code. If you have an error, there is an issue somewhere. What you think you have may not be what you actually have.

Comment: @Seblor: I have mentioned it all now. Please check